Display settings Cinnamon on Ubuntu not working in dynamic environment
I have a big big wish: Could you please put one human ressource on the display settings of ubuntu / cinnamon?
Please, do not test only two connected displays in two standard environments.
I have here the folwooing display situation which ubuntu / cinnamon is not able to cover:

two different graphic cards
from 2 to 4 connected monitors
0 to 2 connected AV receivers

My standard is: 2 Displays connected to one graphic card. One display is rotated, the other not. Both are side by side.
Now I want to switch on a connected AV receiver, which has no connected display, to operate surround sound. The result is: display settings -> a mess
I correct everything with a python script which uses xrandr to setup everything again.
Now I switch on a second AV reciever which is connected to the first AV receiver. The result is: display settings -> a mess -> correction by my own python script
Now I switch on a display which is connected to the second AV receiver. The result is: display settings -> a mess -> correction by my own python script
Now I switch on another display which is connected to a NVidia graphics card. The result is: display settings -> a mess -> correction by my own python script
Now I switch of one of the optional AV receivers or displays. The result is: display settings -> a mess -> correction by my own python script
and so on.
Even when I configure all possible devices in the cinnamon monitor setup app, store everything into the cinnamon-monitors.xml file: It is not working.
I don't know if your world is too simple or you cannot imagine that one is using a computer and software for big projects. But Ubuntu and Cinnamon are not able to support such usecases in terms of display settings.
Please, fix the display setting software or just re-design it and please take into account that there are users outside which have more than one display connected to a computer.
Thank you, yours Matthias
